# When does interpolation happen between the vertex and fragment shaders in this WebGL program?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader, webgl2

## Background

I'm looking at [this example code](https://github.com/tsherif/picogl.js/blob/master/examples/triangle.html) from the WebGL2 library [PicoGL.js](https://tsherif.github.io/picogl.js/).

It describes a single triangle (three vertices: `(-0.5, -0.5), (0.5, -0.5), (0.0, 0.5)`), each of which is assigned a color (red, green, blue) by the vertex shader:

```
    #version 300 es

    layout(location=0) in vec4 position;
    layout(location=1) in vec3 color;

    out vec3 vColor; 
    void main() {
        vColor = color;
        gl_Position = position;
    }
```

The `vColor` output is passed to the fragment shader:

```
    #version 300 es
    precision highp float;

    in vec3 vColor;

    out vec4 fragColor;
    void main() {
        fragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
    }
```

and together they render the following image:

[image: a multicoloured triangle]

## Question(s)

My understanding is that the vertex shader is called once per vertex, whereas the fragment shader is called once per pixel.

However, the fragment shader references the `vColor` variable, which is only assigned once per call to each vertex, but there are many more pixels than vertices!

The resulting image clearly shows a color gradient - why?
Does WebGL automatically interpolate values of `vColor` for pixels in between vertices? If so, how is the interpolation done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, WebGL automatically interpolates between the values supplied to the 3 vertices.

Copied from [this site](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective-correct-texturemapping.html)

> A linear interpolation from one value to another would be this
>   formula
>
> ```
> result = (1 - t) * a + t * b
> ```
>
> Where `t` is a value from 0 to 1 representing some position between `a` and `b`. 0 at `a` and 1 at `b`.
>
> For varyings though WebGL uses this formula
>
> ```
> result = (1 - t) * a / aW + t * b / bW
>          -----------------------------
>             (1 - t) / aW + t / bW
> ```
>
> Where `aW` is the `W` that was set on `gl_Position.w` when the varying was
>   as set to `a` and `bW` is the `W` that was set on `gl_Position.w` when the
>   varying was set to `b`.

The site linked above shows how that formula generates [perspective correct texture mapping coordinates when interpolating varyings](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective-correct-texturemapping.html)

It also [shows an animation of the varyings changing](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html)

Answer (score 4):

The [khronos OpenGL wiki - Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) has the answer. Namely:

> Each fragment has a Window Space position, a few other values, and it contains all of the **interpolated per-vertex output values from the last Vertex Processing stage**.

(Emphasis mine)